# Cant check if an user has attached an image

Tags: android

I'm trying to check if an user has attached an image to an imageview. It seems like it is not returning null and I cant put an error message.

```
imageview.getDrawable() == null
```

is always returning 'true'(I think)
because when I don't put an image it is still inserting the data
It isn't displaying you forgot to fill in some fields

What I have:

```
 boolean hasImage = (imageView.getDrawable() == null);


if (!editTitle.getText().toString().equals("") && !editDescription.getText().toString().equals("") && !hasImage) {
                        boolean isInserted = myDb.insertData(editTitle.getText().toString(), editDescription.getText().toString(), path, longitude, latitude, date);
                    }

if (editTitle.getText().toString().equals("") || editDescription.getText().toString().equals("") || hasImage) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddMomentActivity.this, "You forgot to fill in some fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddMomentActivity.this, "Your Moment has been added!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code.

```
int PICK_IMAGE=1;
ImageView imageView;
boolean hasImage=false;
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setType("image/*");
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE);



  @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
       if(resultCode==Activity.RESULT_OK&&data!null){
        if(requestCode==PICK_IMAGE&&data.getData()!=null){
              Uri uri=data.getData();
              imageView.setImageUri(uri);
              hasImage=true;   //add this line.           
          }
        }
    }
```

By default hasImage has value "false".If the image is successfully picked and attached to imageview,update the hasImage value to "true".This means,that the imageview has some value.

Add this check.

```
if (editTitle.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
||editDescription.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()|| 
hasImage==false) {
     //display toast that some fields are not filled
}else //do something
```

Comment: Good to know. Wc

Answer (score 0):

Try getting image as a bitmap from ImageView

```
Bitmap image=((BitmapDrawable)imageView.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
if(image == null){
  //logic
}
```

Comment: It is still giving the same result. Without an image it is still 'acting' that there is an image